# Creating multiple contexts in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-interface, bounded-contexts

I am struggling to implement multiple database contexts in Entity Framework Code First. I have  already implemented three contexts (all entities, entities related to conference and entities related to user profile) as shown on pictures.
[image: All Entities]

[image: Entities related to conference]

[image: entities related to user profile]

Fluent API is used for entity mappings. For Example this is the code used for ConferenceContext:

```
public class ConferenceContext : BaseContext<ConferenceContext>
{
    public DbSet<Conference> Conferences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ImportantDate> ImportantDates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Venue> Venues { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        insertEntityMappings(modelBuilder); // inserts entity mappings
    }

    private void insertEntityMappings(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ConferenceMappings());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ImportantDateMappings());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TopicMappings());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VenueMappings());

        modelBuilder.Ignore<ConferenceComment>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<ConferenceRating>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<ConnectionConferenceRecommendation>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<UserProfile>();
    }
}

public class ConferenceMappings : EntityTypeConfiguration<Conference>
{
    public ConferenceMappings()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ConferenceId);
        this.Property(t => t.ConferenceId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        this.Property(t => t.Summary)
            .HasMaxLength(1000);

        this.Property(t => t.ContactEmail)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.WebsiteUrl)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.LogoUri)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Conference");
        this.Property(t => t.ConferenceId).HasColumnName("ConferenceId");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        this.Property(t => t.Summary).HasColumnName("Summary");
        this.Property(t => t.ContactEmail).HasColumnName("ContactEmail");
        this.Property(t => t.WebsiteUrl).HasColumnName("WebsiteUrl");
        this.Property(t => t.LogoUri).HasColumnName("LogoUri");
        this.Property(t => t.BegginingDate).HasColumnName("BegginingDate");
        this.Property(t => t.EndingDate).HasColumnName("EndingDate");
        this.Property(t => t.VenueId).HasColumnName("VenueId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.Topics)
            .WithMany(t => t.Conferences)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("TopicConference");
                m.MapLeftKey("Conference_ConferenceId");
                m.MapRightKey("Topic_TopicId");
            });

        this.HasOptional(t => t.Venue)
            .WithMany(t => t.Conferences)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.VenueId);
    }
}

public class ImportantDateMappings : EntityTypeConfiguration<ImportantDate>
{
    public ImportantDateMappings()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ImportantDateId);
        this.Property(t => t.ImportantDateId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.EventName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ImportantDate");
        this.Property(t => t.ImportantDateId).HasColumnName("ImportantDateId");
        this.Property(t => t.Date).HasColumnName("Date");
        this.Property(t => t.EventName).HasColumnName("EventName");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Conference)
            .WithMany(t => t.ImportantDates)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ConferenceId);
    }
}

public class TopicMappings : EntityTypeConfiguration<Topic>
{
    public TopicMappings()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.TopicId);
        this.Property(t => t.TopicId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Topic");
        this.Property(t => t.TopicId).HasColumnName("TopicId");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
    }
}

public class VenueMappings : EntityTypeConfiguration<Venue>
{
    public VenueMappings()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.VenueId);
        this.Property(t => t.VenueId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Address)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.City)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.State)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Venue");
        this.Property(t => t.VenueId).HasColumnName("VenueId");
        this.Property(t => t.Address).HasColumnName("Address");
        this.Property(t => t.City).HasColumnName("City");
        this.Property(t => t.State).HasColumnName("State");
        this.Property(t => t.CountryId).HasColumnName("CountryId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Country)
            .WithMany(t => t.Venues)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CountryId);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to create Context that is similar to one shown on the picture below.

[image: New Context]

Comment: I have to say that I already tried to implement this context, by creating new classes which contain wanted properties only and mapping them to the same table. That approach didn't work for me (maybe I missed something) because code trowed an exception telling me that it can't match to the database structure. Considering this, I also want to ask, is this even possible?

Comment: If you are trying to map existing database with EF Code First, there are tools that help you generate classes from database schema. Look for it. I think one was Entity Framework Power Tools.

Comment: I know. I used that tool to generate these diagrams. I think you didn't understand my question. I have created three contexts shown on top, but I couldn't create the last one. I have created POCOs with properties that I need and mapped them to the same table. EF Power Tools generated the last diagram from those new classes, but the problem occurs at runtime because EF can't map those classes to corresponding tables.